# Matlab Specifying Variable Continous Range in Equation

Tags: matlab, plot, equation

I am trying to get solutions of a equation and then plot the result on a graph in MATLAB. Suppose, if a equation is,

R=A*sin(theta)

Where, A is a variable, say from 0 to 5 (which will be plotted on x-axis) and theta is from 0 to 3. The resultant values of R, for continous range of A i.e. 0 to 5, will be plotted on y-axis.

I would like to ask that, in MATLAB, how can I get a continous range of variable A, (and that of theta as well), so that I can plot the values on a graph with respective continous-values (or resultant values) of R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ezplot(fun, [xmin xmax])`:

```
theta = pi;
R =@(A) A*sin(theta);
ezplot(R,[0 5]);
```

**EDIT:**

In case you want theta range as well you can use the 3D equivalent: `ezsurf` or `fsurf(fun, [xmin xmax ymin ymax])`, like that:

```
R = @(theta,A) A*sin(theta);
ARange = [0 5];
thetaRange = [0 3];
fsurf(R,[thetaRange ARange]);
xlabel('\theta')
ylabel('A')
title('A\cdotsin(\theta)')
```

Comment: May I ask that you have assigned,theta=pi, will it cause the value of theta to be of the range between 0 to 3? In addition, how can I plot a 3d graph for the above equation with theta (x-axis), A (y-axis) and resultant R(z-axis)?